# Whenever/When I wake up late, I go to bed and fall asleep after 10 p.m. - does this make sense?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

When expressing a habitual or repetitive event using "when" or "whenever", can there be a period of time between the events?

For example

**Example 1**

> "Whenever/When I wake up late, I go to bed and fall asleep after 10 p.m."

**Example 2**

> "Whenever/When I go jogging in the morning, I go to bed and fall asleep at 10 p.m."

Comment: I take it going to bed at 10pm is ***late*** for the cited speaker. So what he's saying is on days when he gets up late, he also goes to bed late. I'd use ***if*** rather than ***when / whenever***, but the "consequence" part of the statement as given doesn't sound very natural to me anyway. I'd say ***If** I wake up late, I **don't** go to bed and fall asleep **until** after 10 p.m.*

Comment: "if" is better because "when/whenever" suggests simultaneous actions?
Take this following sentence as an example, "Whenever/When I wake up late in the morning, I go to bed and fall asleep after 10 p.m." This doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Making sense and grammar are two different things. when/whenever are fine and mean the same thing. "if" is just another way to say it.

Comment: I don't see any reason to suppose *"when/whenever" suggests simultaneous actions* any more or less than ***if*** would. But [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=When+I+do+that%2CIf+I+do+that&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that we're much more likely to say ***If** I do that...* rather than ***When** I do that...* There's nothing *wrong* with ***when / whenever*** in your context, and there's not much scope for a difference in meaning. It's just that ***if*** is more common.